# Koala - likes edge responds in graph API explorer but not to koala code

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I've written some code in Ruby using the koala library. What I'm trying to to do is get a few page edges like so:

```
     line = 110360775652715
     x = line.to_s+"/posts"
     posts = @graph.get_objects(x)
```

When I use my code to run this, I get the following error merrage:

```
    Error: type: OAuthException, code: 803, message: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 110360775652715/posts [HTTP 404]
```

However, when I feed

```
    110360775652715/posts
```

directly into the graph API explorer developer tool, I get a proper response. My access token is fine, it's not expired or anything.

What gives?

Edit: I know my question talks about the 'likes' edge but I have the same issue for 'posts' as well, so I figured it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The correct call is `@graph.get_connections`

For example `@graph.get_connections('boo','posts')`

That `get_objects` is for requesting multiple objects in one call
https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/ffa1dc61cf06a5c875567c1442db04956754b811/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb#L69

```
ids = ['boo','4']
profile = @graph.get_objects(ids)
```

With the response as

```
=> {
    "4" => {
        "id" => "4", "first_name" => "Mark", "last_name" => "Zuckerberg", "link" => "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/4/", "name" => "Mark Zuckerberg", "updated_time" => "2015-12-02T02:25:29+0000"
    }, "boo" => {
        "id" => "80329313253", "about" => "My name is Boo. I am a dog. Life is good.", "affiliation" => "Dog", "birthday" => "03/16/2006", "can_post" => false, "category" => "Public Figure", "checkins" => 0, "cover" => {
            "cover_id" => "10153114279788254", "offset_x" => 0, "offset_y" => 0, "source" => "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/t31.0-8/s720x720/10633949_10153114279788254_8392027345261588939_o.jpg", "id" => "10153114279788254"
        }, "has_added_app" => false, "is_community_page" => false, "is_published" => true, "likes" => 17345372, "link" => "https://www.facebook.com/Boo/", "name" => "Boo", "parking" => {
            "lot" => 0, "street" => 0, "valet" => 0
        }, "personal_info" => "Boo the World's Cutest Dog\nInstagram: @buddyboowaggytails\nTwitter: @buddyANDboo", "personal_interests" => "Favorite foods:  chicken, cheese, flowers, grass, dirt ...\n\nFavorite games: running outside, following around big bro, squeaky toys!\n\nFavorite pastime: wearing shirts\n\nFavorite color: pink\n", "talking_about_count" => 401445, "username" => "Boo", "website" => "http://www.facebook.com/Boo", "were_here_count" => 0
    }
}
```

Additionally the ID you are requesting is for a merged wiki page, so you will not get the same data as a normal page.

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cheating-in-video-games/108346199186173?rf=110360775652715

Comment: And where do merged wiki pages fit in? I haven't seem them on the graph api docs before

Comment: @tvishwa107 wiki pages don't fit in so I'm unclear what data you are trying to get from that page.

Comment: I could have been more clear I think, the number here is just a placeholder :) 
I didn't know it was a wiki page, I was only giving an example from a set of numbers I had

Answer (score 0):

This was just carelessness. I've been sending the

```
   get_objects
```

call which is for multiple objects instead of

```
   get_object
```

which is more suitable since I have only one object.